# \counterwithout and \captionlistentry leads to omitting figure numbering

Tags: subcaption, chngcntr

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[]{todonotes} % only for the dummy-figure
\usepackage[]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{hyperref} % needs to be loaded AFTER chngcntr (see comments)
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{.32\textwidth}
            \centering
            \missingfigure{dummy1}
            \captionlistentry{}
            \label{fig:1a}
        \end{subfigure}

        \begin{subfigure}[b]{.32\textwidth}
            \missingfigure{dummy2}
            \captionlistentry{}
            \label{fig:1b}
        \end{subfigure}

        \caption[]{whatever.}
        \label{fig:1}
    \end{figure}

\begin{figure}
        \centering
        \missingfigure{dummy1}
        \caption{}
    \label{fig:2}
\end{figure}

Reference to figure 1: \autoref{fig:1}
figure 2: \autoref{fig:2}

figure 1a: \autoref{fig:1a}

\end{document}
```

What I want is a continuous figure numbering (1, 2, 3, aso., independent of chapter).
I have TeXstudio installed in Ubuntu (13.10) (TeXstudio 2.6.6) and Windows 8.1 (TeXstudio 2.10.4). When I compile the above MWE with TeXstudio in Ubuntu, I get the figure numbering exactly as expected:

[image]

However, when I compile it in Windows, I get this:

[image]

I think I see what's happening here, but I don't know how to solve it.

Edit: `fig:2` is not missing, it just floats on the 2nd page which I didn't screenshot. The issue is just about the numbering.

Comment: Try to load `hyperref` **after** `\counterwithout`! I can't test since I am not using Windows

Comment: Tried that, but same result.

Comment: The correct load order is `\usepackage{chngcntr}` , `\usepackage{hyperref}` *afterwards* (so hyperref can patch the code provided by chngcntr), and finally `\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}` (so the code patched by hyperref gets used). As an alternative you could drop the usage of the `chngcntr` package and use the `caption` package option `figurewithout` instead: `\usepackage[figurewithout]{caption}`. (No need to take care about the load order here since the `caption` package is adapted to the `hyperref` package.)

Comment: BTW: What version of the `caption` package do you use when compiling on Windows?

Comment: Updating the `caption` package (30449 -> 38425) on Windows did it - thanks! (I should have checked that first…)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was due to outdated software and has been solved with an update